# SSH: Listen on 2 networks, operating with different rules

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a set of VMs, which have a network private to them, and then they each have a public IP.  Is it possible to have a set of rules for the public IP (say no password authentication, non-standard port) and the have another set of rule for the private network (password authentication, port 22) for ssh?

This is on Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: What operating system is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't necessary to configure a second instance for this.  Check the "Match" keyword in the [sshd_config manpage](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5)

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a solution like this, thank you

Answer (score 6):

Install/configure another instance of sshd to run under the different set of rules.  Check out [this link](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2006-September/093067.html) for hints.

Comment: upvoting because this is on the right lines. No need to install twice though, just use two config files for sshd and use -f when launcing the server (twice).

Comment: I figured that this would probably be the way to have this work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Sirex; +1 to you!  I didn't think that it would be necessary to install a second instance, but I don't have a *nix box to try on.  Changed "Install" to "Install/Configure"